# Help with a mechanics question on forces and motion

Tags: classical-mechanics, projectile-motion

I’m having some trouble with a worksheet I was given for undergraduate mechanics. I didn’t have any lectures in this topic due to strikes happening at my university, so any help with how to answer part b) would be hugely appreciated.

[image]

(edit) This is what I got for part a): [my answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzrAp.jpg)
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you found out, what are your results for a), where exactly do lie your problems?

Answer (score 1):

Under the announced forces the movement reads

$$
-m g \hat k + m \lambda \hat i - m \mu\dot z \hat k = m(\ddot x\hat i + \ddot z \hat k)
$$

or

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\ddot x & = & \lambda \\
\ddot z +\mu \dot z + g & = & 0\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Now solving for the velocities

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
v_ x & = & \lambda t + v_{x_0}\\
v_ z & = & -g/\mu + v_{z_0}e^{-\mu t}\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

If the elapsed time is such that $e^{-\mu t} \ll 1$ then $\vert{v_z} \vert\approx \vert v_{z_\infty} \vert= g/\mu$.

Here

$$
\vert v\vert\ = \sqrt{v_x^2+v_{z_\infty}^2}
$$

Comment: I honestly have no idea what any of that means. I've had zero lectures on this topic due to the strikes, and minimal help since. I'll edit my original question with what I got for part a)

Comment: You should find that $v_z=-g/μ+(v_{z0}+g/μ)e^{−μt}$ to get $v_{z0}$ at $t=0$.

Comment: So how do I get to here? I'm trying to do it as a differential equation, but i'm just getting nowhere with it. I've tried $z=e^{kt}$